# Wrong rendering in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using [Zend Framework  1.11.4](http://zendframework.com) , when i preview each URL of my site, returnd HTML has some character that i dont know their source!!

This characters is in the top of returnd HTML(before `doctype`) and this cause to wrong rendering in Ineternet Explorer(because it prevents to know ie to the correct Doctype).
have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's (well, may be) [UTF8's BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark). Good editors can turn them off. You're either using a bad one or a good one inpropperly configured :)

Answer (score 0):

My first though would be to copy the offending characters to the clipboard and then search through your source code, using grep for example, for these characters. Chances are there is a random string in your view somewhere. This would be the first thing to rule out.

Answer (score 0):

i can only think of you probably having empty lines or other garbage in your source files, you shoudn't close your php tags,

> First of all, PHP doesn’t require it,
>   so you even save a few bits on your
>   total filesize. But the most important
>   reason is that it prevents additional
>   whitespace that could really mess up
>   your website or application.

you can search around round google for a better explanation of why

Comment: Searched too much!Have you any link?

Comment: see http://www.finishjoomla.com/blog/20/the-php-closing-tag-explained/ and http://leftofreality.net/2010/02/24/omitting-the-closing-tag-in-php-files/